# how can i change a sentence with a time range?

Tags: reactjs

How can I change a sentence with a time range in React.js?

For example, I have a 10-second interval, it starts with a sentence, in second 2 it changes to another sentence and in second 4 it goes back to the initial sentence

For example, I have a 10-second interval, it starts with a sentence, in second 2 it changes to another sentence and in second 4 it goes back to the initial sentence

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need something like this:

```
 const [sentence, setSentence] = useState("First sentence");
  const intervalRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    intervalRef.current = setInterval(() => {
      if (sentence === "First sentence") {
        setSentence("Second sentence");
      } else {
        setSentence("First sentence");
      }
    }, 2000);

    // Clear the interval
    setTimeout(() => {
      clearInterval(intervalRef.current);
    }, 11000); // Setting 11 because it would stop before the final change if it was 10

    return () => clearInterval(intervalRef.current);
  }, [sentence]);

  return <div>{sentence}</div>;
```

This will change sentance every 2 seconds for up to 10 seconds total. Using ref to be something like a counter.